# Gradle task executes is Configuration phase but not in Execution phase

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle task which simply copies the files from one folder to another.

When the copy 'from' 'into' methods are called during configuration phase it works but when they are called in the execution phase it doesn't.

Doing it this way it works

```
task copyServerConfig(type:Copy)  {  
    from "${projectDir}" + File.separator + 'server_config'  
    into localServer  
}
```

gradle copyServerConfig

```
:copyServerConfig  

BUILD SUCCESSFUL  

Total time: 0.686 secs
```

With the '<<' it doesn't show any error but the files are not copied:

```
task copyServerConfig(type:Copy) << {  
    from "${projectDir}" + File.separator + 'server_config'  
    into localServer  
}
```

gradle copyServerConfig

```
:copyServerConfig UP-TO-DATE  

BUILD SUCCESSFUL  

Total time: 0.654 secs
```

Same thing happen if I put it inside a doFirst{} block.

Another thing I don't understand is the following:

If I execute this task:

```
task task1(type:Exec) << {  
     commandLine 'echo', ' TEST'   
}
```

I get this error:

gradle task1

```
:task1 FAILED  

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:  
Execution failed for task ':task1'.  
execCommand == null!
```

But if I change to this:

```
task task1(type:Exec) {  
     commandLine 'echo', ' TEST'   
}
```

gradle task1

```
:task1  
 TEST  

BUILD SUCCESSFUL  

Total time: 0.655 secs
```

I read in the documentation about the about build lifecycle and I understand commands inside doFirst{} and doLast{} blocks execute during the Execution phase and commands outside those blocks execute in the Configuration phase.

But I think there is some important concept I am missing here. Why is this happening ? What is the difference of having a command being executed in the Configuration phase vs Execution phase ?

Answer (score 2):

The first variant is a correct way to declare a Copy task

```
task copyServerConfig(type:Copy)  {  
    from "${projectDir}" + File.separator + 'server_config'  
    into localServer  
}
```

Here you say "this is a task of type `Copy` with name `copyServerConfig`, this is `from` param and this is `into` param". The code inside the brackets is used to *configure* a task.

---

`<<` operator adds a `doAfter` closure to the task, that is executed after it.

```
task copyServerConfig(type:Copy) << {  
    from "${projectDir}" + File.separator + 'server_config'  
    into localServer  
}
```

This declaration means "create empty (not configured) `Copy` task and execute these two lines after it is done. Here you did not configure a task, it does nothing and is always `UP-TO-DATE`. The two lines in `doAfter` closure do nothing as well, because they are not related to `Copy` task, so `from` and `into` keywords have no effect.

---

The similar thing happens with `Exec` task

```
task task1(type:Exec) << {  
     commandLine 'echo', ' TEST'   
}
```

Here you have empty Exec task that fails because it is not configured.